# Auto update for android application

Tags: android

I am updating my application by incrementing the version code and version name. But I don't get an auto update option or notification for this application. My auto update option in google play store in enabled and notifications appear for other apps. What I am missing ?

Comment: it takes upto 4 hours for update to appear

Comment: Its not your responsibility, you just need to replace apk file.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Play Console takes some time to get the application indexed and updated..some times it may take upto 24 hours.

Comment: yes and I get the update option when I go to play store. Just don't get auto updated like other apps